# Koala::Facebook::ClientError Exception: type: GraphMethodException, code: 100, message: Unsupported get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4.1, koala-gem

I did research on this issue, however, nothing worked for me.

I am using Facebook Realtime subscription and graph API to track my facebook page (using page token).

When a user posts a photo/video I am getting following data pushed by fb to my server:

```
{"field"=>"feed",
 "value"=>
  {"item"=>"photo",
   "verb"=>"add",
   "photo_id"=>302522856593533,
   "post_id"=>"824413870916335_302522856593533",
   "sender_id"=>100005074631221}}
```

When I use `post_id (824413870916335_302522856593533)` to make call to graph API for fetching details of the post, I am encountering following error:

> *** Koala::Facebook::ClientError Exception: type: GraphMethodException, code: 100, message: Unsupported get request.
>   Please read the Graph API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api [HTTP 400]

However, **if user posts without photo/video, I am able to get post details successfully**. In case, admin posts photo/video, I am able to get details of that post too.

I am sure about the correctness of page token and code. I think, there must be something related to settings.

[image]

Comment: facing a similar issue with my code.

Comment: @QaiserWali for me, it worked as it is next day! may be some temporary issue with fb..

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple pages to fetch.  Tested with both of these methods Koala wiki provides

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new # pre 1.2beta
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new # 1.2beta and beyond
```

Some pages have ids and some have not in their uris so in a page like this:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Istanbul-Kuafor/241559912664906

```
 fc.get_object("Istanbul-Kuafor")
```

gives me the error message you mentioned so I use

```
fc.get_object("241559912664906")
```

if page doesn't have an id(some pages don't, somehow), I use the page name and it works this time.